# Play Framework 2.1.1 HTTP 413 trigger

Tags: http, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am having problems with Play! `Framework 2.1.1`

When sending a large(100kb+) request to my application (Play! 2.1.1) i get a "413 Request Entity Too Large" which is fine because 100kb limit is default.

However if i send around 104kb(maybe this number is just for me) i get a 200 OK again, but with the `request().body()` as null and therefore all Form entities as well...

Why am i getting a 200 OK and getting my code run when it should return 413?

A hack-ish fix could be(in my Global.java which extends GlobalSettings):

```
@Override
public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
    if(request.body().isMaxSizeExceeded()) {
        return new Action.Simple() {

            @Override
            public Result call(Context arg0) throws Throwable {
                return Action.status(413);
            }
        };
    }
    return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
}
```

**EDIT:** The above code makes all(?) routes' requests return 413.

I'd prefer to return JSON in case of a 413. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Maybe this is a bug? Looking at the documentation over at [Play 2.1.1 docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaBodyParsers), although its the scala doc(it should be the same for java?), it says  

`Note: That’s why a body parser is not really an Iteratee[Array[Byte],A] but more precisely a Iteratee[Array[Byte],Either[Result,A]], meaning that it has the opportunity to send directly an HTTP result itself (typically 400 BAD_REQUEST, 412 PRECONDITION_FAILED or 413 REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE) if it decides that it is not able to compute a correct value for the request body`

Comment: I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1473) over at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1473